# Why is there a custom to join "Hashem" and "Elokenu" together in the line Al Taazvenu in Shema Kolenu in Selichot

Tags: grammar-dikduk, tehilim-psalms, selichot

In Shema Kolenu, based on the Posuk in [Psalms 38:22](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c2638.htm#22) we say the phrase:

> Al Taazvenu Hashem Elokenu Al tirchak mimenu | Don't leave us Hashem Our God Don't distance yourself from us.

The interesting thing is that, although it seems many people have a custom whilst reciting this phrase to join the words `Hashem` and `Our God` together and put a comma after the word `God` (and, indeed, there are Siddurim that have a comma at this point in the text), this appears to be incorrect. When one checks the Posuk that the phrase is based upon in the Tehillim, there is a break after the word `Hashem`, and the phrase `Our God` is part of the next clause.

The way most people seem to have a custom to say it:

> Don't leave us Hashem Our God; don't distance yourself from us.

The (seemingly) correct way, following the verse:

> Don't leave us Hashem; Our God don't distance yourself from us.

I always thought people were just ignorant of the fact that that it is not joined in the Posuk. But when I heard a Choshuve Rov daven for the Amud and he said that together, I had to ask him what is the Pshat. He told me that he knows that it is not the correct way according to the Posuk, but he has a minhag to say it like that, and that it might possibly come from Muncatch. He could offer no further details.

Can you tell me when this Minhag started and who started it?
Can you tell me why this Minhag started?
Or have you got another reason to judge favourably the thousands of Yidden who otherwise seem to be reading it wrong?

Comment: In the Nusach Ari Selichos (published by Kehos) the posuk is printed with the comma after אלקינו. Also note that the posuk it is not an exact quote from Tehilim.

Comment: agreed, but the only difference between Tehillim is the plural. I doubt that the meaning would have changed. +1 for noting the Nusach Ari, it makes it even more interesing. When was it first printed and what was the format then?

Comment: I am not sure when exactly it was printed, as I was just checking from a [pdf online](http://beta.chabad.org/media/pdf/56/JODh562118.pdf) (page 15). It's a fairly new edition though. Iy"h tommorow morning I'll have a look in my selichos in shul, and as well at older prints.

Comment: The Selichos was printed in 2005. Interestingly, in the old editions there is no comma.

Comment: @Michoel I suspected as much. Appreciate your time!

Comment: Rosenfeld 1956 edition has a full-stop _between_ "HaShem" and "Our G-d" (end of sentences get a colon, so I assume it is meant as a comma).

Comment: @SethJ nice find

Comment: I just happened to use it and noticed AND remembered to comment. :)

Comment: _Trop_ put the break between _Hashem_ and _elohi_ in Tehillim 38:22.

Comment: Fwiw, my _Machzor Ivri-Teitch_ has "_v'al tirchak_" in some places.

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.102.28 another verse from prayers around there often misparsed

Comment: I didn't know people say it say it out loud- shuls stop saying together after the two "al tashlichienu" pesukim.

Comment: why is it necessary for the grammar of the sentence to be the same when the words are different from what is in tehillim?

Comment: Why does the answer need to be any more than that it rhymes that way and/or "hashem elokeinu" is a common enough phrase that the mistake is very easy to make, especially considering how rare expertise in precise grammatical reading of scripture is nowadays?

Comment: The yekkish selichos book has a comma in between Hashem and Elokeinu.

Comment: Probably in Munkach they didn't know the grammar and wrote some tune which butchered the meaning (a known longstanding issue in Jewish liturgical musical composition). He may be correct that he has a Minhag but he doesn't realize it's a Minhag Shtus which isn't binding and should be abandoned.

Comment: @msh210 see [this slichos minhag polin](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=j6JEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT78&lpg=PT78&dq=%D7%90%D7%9C+%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95+%D7%94%27+%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95&source=bl&ots=cnY5nAG3q2&sig=yZe9teBnRruqSnCKdzd7aH9e1o0&hl=iw&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%94'%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95&f=false) it has ואל** תרחק ממנו ** like you said your machzor has.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a question of whether both names are being invoked for both pleas, or whether each plea gets its own name.

Is seems difficult to bring a proof from the Passuk itself, as i'm assuming that the OP is referring to the Taamim, and the Taamim are tricky in Tehillim. Also, it would seem that even though there is indeed a hisnachta under HaShem, there is an azla-geireish under Elokai, which indicates a phrase for itself, so I am not so sure if the Hisnachta is such a good proof in this case, since the word Elokai also has a phrase-ender so to speak (correct me if i'm wrong).

This brings it down to the Meforshim, to see if they split up the names or not.

The Radak and the Alshich do explain that Al Taazveini is a plea to the name Hashem, and Al tirchak mimeni is a plea to the name Elokai.

On the other hand the Malbim bunches both pleas together without pointing out any separation. Moreover, and perhaps the best source for this minhag to put the two names together, the Rokeach (Rabbi Elazar of Worms, circa 1160-1260) in his commentary on the siddur, clearly puts the two names together:

פירושי סידור התפילה לרוקח [סט] אנא מלך חנון ורחום עמוד שפט
אל תעזבינו ה' אלהינו אל תרחק ממנו הואיל ואתה חוזק שלנו ואלהינו, אין לך 
לעזבינו בצרותינו ולא לירחק ממנו.

"Since you are our strength and our God (Elokeinu), you must not forsake us in our angst, nor must you not distance yourself from us."

This would clearly require a reading of the passuk the way the minhag is according to the OP.

Comment: You are wrong. The taamim are very, very unambiguous, even if you are correct that many people don't know how to read taamim in tehillim. Also fyi the note on Elokai isn't an Azla Geresh but rather a Revii Mugrash which functions sort of like a Tipcha in ordinary verses.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the Rokeach clearly puts the names together. He does no such thing as far as I can see. He lists two reasons and two consequences. Seems more like there's an implied "respectively" going on here.

Comment: As to the reading of the Radak, i do not see it your way, rather i see it as a clear attemt to group the names and the pleas together, as i stated. I respect your opinion, but let us let the readers decide.

Comment: Note that i didn't say the taamim have not meaning, rather i suggested they are tricky. I am surely a rookie on the issue, i make no authoritative statements about them. Am i also wrong about the Phrase ender idea?