# What is the function of "Eloheinu" in blessings?

Tags: blessing, words, shemos-sacred-names, malchut-royalty

Many blessings open with the familiar formula:

> ברוך אתה יהוה אלהינו מלך העולם

In additions, many blessings close with the familiar shorter formula:

> ברוך אתה יהוה

Now, we know (Berakhot 40b, Rambam Berakhot 1:5, ShA OC 214) that a proper blessing needs to contain mention of both God's name and His kingship (Shem uMalkhut). Clearly "יהוה" is a part of the former of those requirements and "מלך העולם" is a part of the latter. Where does "אלהינו" fit in?

On the one hand, אלהינו is a name of God which cannot be erased (Rambam Yesodei 7:2, ShA YD 276:9) so it seems to be part of the "Shem" part of the formulation. Mishna Berura (214 sk 4) rules that אלהינו alone can function as the Shem in a blessing. Indeed the combo "יהוה אלהינו" appears quite frequently in Tanakh (with conjunctive Trop on the first word), and, [even when unwarranted, people automatically run them together](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19129/759).

On the other hand, in the shorter closing formulation of longer blessings the chosen name of God to use is not "יהוה אלהינו" but just "יהוה". I can accept that Malkhut need not be mentioned again at the conclusion, but why should only part of the Shem be left out? It's worth noting that [the name אלהינו has associations with Divine Judgement](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57716/759) which in a certain sense fits more with Malkhut than Shem.

I note that in many prayer books there are Trop marks on the blessing preceding the Haftarah, opening with בר֨וך את֤ה יהוה֙ אלהינו֙ מ֣לך העול֔ם which, by putting the primary division on יהוה, indicates אלהינו is part of the latter phrase. However, these notes are of unknown origin and clearly do not conform to the regular rules of Trop (you can't have two Pashtas in a row unless they follow a Revi'i; I suspect the notes were just lifted from [Chronicles 1:29:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c25a29.htm#10) without much thought to context). Hence, I don't think this should be taken as conclusive evidence.

I note as well that in my experience, those who say "Barukh Hu Uvarukh Shemo" when hearing God's name in a blessing (cf. OC 124:5) do so after hearing the word יהוה but before the word אלהינו (eg. during the Chazzan's recitation of the morning blessings), indicating a separation in the blessing. As before though, this could be a carryover from, for example, the repetition of the Shemoneh Esrei where that phrase is regularly used in the context of the shorter closing formulae of blessings.

So which side is it? Is "אלהינו" in a standard blessing part of the Shem or part of the Malkhut? If part of the Shem, then why leave it off in the closing formula and pause between the two halves of the Shem? Proofs from earlier sources (≥Rishonim) are especially sought.

Comment: Note fwiw that _Sh'ma…_ is one of the _malchuyos_ verses.

Comment: It seems that Tosfot on Berachot 40b considers "אלהינו" not to represent "מלכות" (he says that *amida* doesn't have "מלכות", and that its replacement is "אלהי אברהם"). He also explains why "שמע ישראל" is considered "מלכות", which also strengthens the idea that he didn't think "אלהינו" is enough. On the other hand, one can argue that he thinks that "אלהינו" isn't "מלכות" *on its own*, though I think the former is correct. Also Yalkut Yosef (214, 1) definitely thinks "אלהינו" is part of the "שם".

Comment: If it was shem, and one can have a construction with the shem and not malchut, would that make "Baruch elokeinu sheb'ra'anu lichvodo" a complete construction of a blessing?

Comment: @Danno Yes, I considered that. Particularly problematic if you think Eloheinu can function as both Shem and Malkhut.

Comment: @Cauthon Yalkut Yosef here http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_15.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L2 says along the lines of the Mishna Berura. It's possible IMO that a Malkhut phrase could use a name of God in it without intending to be the Shem. In a case where Havaya was omitted, then we're breaking the standard structure anyway and Eloheinu changes it's function.

Comment: Possibly relevant https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%96_%D7%92

Comment: @Cauthon I'm not seeing a proof in Tosfot. He says the Amida doesn't have the obvious Malkhut words "Melekh haOlam" but it still qualifies as having Malkhut in it because of the word "Elohei Avraham". Sounds like he thinks Eloheinu could be Malkhut. He's just answering the question someone might have about how "Melekh haOlam" could be missing. Answer: Elohei X is Malkhut too.

Comment: I agree with the notion that "אלהינו" could be both, since it is obviously a name, but it also represents His dominion over us and the world. About Tosfot, if his opinion that "אלהינו" is enough for "מלכות", he would simply answer that we do have "שם ומלכות", with the simple "אלהינו". Instead, he asks where is the "מלכות", and answers that it is in "אלהי אברהם", and not in "אלהינו", so it would seem that he doesn't think "אלהינו" represents "מלכות". Also here's an [opinion](http://www.hidabroot.org/he/question/29750), but unsourced unfortunately.

Comment: Also, in the Yalkut Yosef it seems that his opinion is that "אלהינו" is part of the "שם" as well. He first speaks about a partial "מלכות", that is allowed בדיעבד. Then he speaks about a partial "שם", that is allowed בדיעבד - by either omitting "הויה" or omitting "אלהינו".

Comment: @Cauthon Oh I see. Why answer with Elohei Avraham instead of Eloheinu. Good point.

Comment: Another possibly relevant [Girsa in] Tosfot http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=54b&format=pdf

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20697&st=&pgnum=158 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20697&st=&pgnum=82

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=82330&rid=944

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9600&st=&pgnum=224&hilite=

Comment: I remember that the Siddur Tzlosa de-Avraham points out that in the vernacular version בריך רחמנא מלכא דעלמא מריה דהאי פיתא there is no word corresponding to אלהינו.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61728/759

Comment: Yarchon HaOtzar v37

Comment: As far as the trop marks on the blessing before the Haftara, I suspect they might have been added because the previous tune might have contributed towards inducing people to wrongly answer amein after "הנאמרים באמת", whereas the current pseudo-esnachta specifically induces people not to answer amein (see *Mishna B'rura* 284:6, citing Acharonim). As it is, a similar problem persists in the first blessing after the Haftara, following the words "אמת וצדק".

Comment: @Fred my instinct is to not find that plausible but I have no proof. Worth noting while here that some rites do specifically stop at both the places you are saying shouldn't be stopped at.

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair enough. לשנה טובה תכתב ותחתם לאלתר לחיים טובים ולשלום!

Comment: @Fred Amen וכן למר

Answer (score 1):

From the Kabale point of view, Elokeinu refers to Gvurah, which is usually translated into rigor and justice.

This world is under Gvurah attribute (Yalkut shim'oni).

Malkhut isn't Gvurah : Malkhut is reign. In fact, it is the attribute that is above and below in Sder Hischtalchelous. Which means Malkhut transfers all 9 attributes above her to the world below.

Then one knows why Elokeinu comes in this order: Malkhut is below (and above as well) the Gvurah attribute. However, making a blessing means elevating a profane object to being Kadosh. For this reason, you refer to all successive levels of Gd presence into the blessing, and there you go : Malkout is under Gvurah, in that case.

Now, Elokeinu functions as a common denomination in scriptures to describe forces that can be considered as divinities by men ('asseret diberos, parachas Kedochim...). So, it could appear not directly linked to Jews Gd.

However, Elokeinu is undoubtedly a Name; which has the Gmatria *Hateva'* (the Nature), and is the expression of Gd under the Gvurah attribute. Also, it is said "Havaye hou haElokim".

The fact that it can be used to describe other divinities as well is a proof of the fact that Gd's presence under those circumstances is a bit hidden. Elokim is hence **a denomination of a leading divinity**. This is the most direct reference for men who accept it as such. You hence got a "neutral" divinity on one side, and a direct proof of reign on the other (since it is also an attribute expression).

So that Elokeinu is both Malkhut and a Shem.

Comment: The parts of this post that address the question, simply say both themes I noted are real so it's both. It says this without sources, and without addressing why, if it is Shem, certain things are surprising as noted in the question. This answer is not very useful, as I could have speculated about it being both before you did, and your speculation lacks value as I don't know you that I should trust you.