# Parsing Shehechiyyanu

Tags: grammar-dikduk, trop-cantillation, shehecheyanu

When reading the *megilloth* in *shul* from a *klaf*, many say the blessing of *shehechiyyanu*<sup>1</sup>.  I have noticed that many people sing this blessing in its own tune (ie. not in trope), but I have also heard it read using the trope about to be used for that *megillah*.

In order to use trope, we need to first grammatically parse the sentence.

For the parsing of the first half, see [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69371/4940)<sup>2</sup>.  For the second half, do we understand:

(a) ‮(שהחינו וקימנו והיגענו) (לזמן הזה)

where לזמן הזה applies to all the verbs<sup>3</sup>, or

(b) (שהחינו וקימנו) (והגיענו לזמן הזה)

where לזמן הזה only applies to the last verb<sup>4</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> See [S"A O"H 692:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3072) for *Esther*, [Ma'aseh Rav 175](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91#.D7.A7.D7.A2.D7.94) for *Shir HaShirim*.  See also sources [here](http://etzion.org.il/en/shiur-05-reciting-blessing-over-five-megillot) and [here](http://etzion.org.il/en/shiur-06-reciting-blessing-over-five-megillot-ii).
<sup>2</sup> Perhaps one would do: *pashta munach zakef-qaton tipcha munach etnachta*.
<sup>3</sup> Hence, perhaps: *darga tvir tipcha mercha siluq* (cf. [Deut 33:27](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0533.htm#26)).
<sup>4</sup> Hence, perhaps: *pashta zakef-qaton tipcha mercha siluq* (cf. [Num 4:31](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0404.htm#31)).  I would think something similar also applies to the blessing על מקרא מגילה: *mapakh pashta zakef-qaton tipcha mercha siluq* (cf. [Ex 33:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0233.htm#10)) (or arguably *pashta munach zakef-qaton*).

Comment: I have heard 4 used in this context. See too https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10695/759

Comment: Interestingly, minor variants of the "popular" tune might imply either A or B. For A: https://youtu.be/IRPlaotwAe4?t=74, while (possibly) for B: https://youtu.be/0hNLe8muleU?t=39

Comment: I have never heard trope used for Shehechiyanu. But, to me,  choice b seems to be the more logical choice. Reason - "Living" is general, and you are glad that G-d has sustained our life for an indefinite time period; establishing (loose translation of 2nd term) is also for indefinite period; "Higiyanu" means to "bring us" or "allow us to arrive" - can that be indefinite? Arrive for what? - "lazman hazeh" which is the object of only "higiyanu" and not the other verbs.

Comment: @DanF לזמן הזה clearly _does_ refers to הגיענו. The question is whether it also refers to the other verbs. Yeah, I'm glad God has sustained my life for an indefinite time period (and would like him to continue sustaining my life), but maybe right now I'm thanking him for sustaining my life to right now.